# jquery - how to change "src" attribute of image in callback of animate method?

Tags: jquery

I want to change src of image after completing some animation,
but my code (http://jsfiddle.net/QJKWK/1/) doesn't work.

```
$("div").append("<img src = 'http://ecreative.6f.sk/img/iphone.png' />");
var img = $("div:last");
img.animate({width: "500px"}, 1000, function() {
    img.attr("src",  "http://ecreative.6f.sk/img/sonos.png");
});
```

Could somebody please explain why not?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: your fiddle is working, define "doesn't work"

Comment: Image doesn't change after completing the animation.

Comment: There's no animation in this fiddle..

Comment: Yes it is, img.animate({width: "500px"}

Answer (score 5):

Because you aren't targeting the `img`. Use like this:

```
img.animate({width: "500px"}, 1000, function() {
    img.find('img').attr("src",  "http://ecreative.6f.sk/img/sonos.png");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJKWK/3/)

Comment: @AmitJoki added the fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I can't understand, why for animate() there is no need for use find() and for attr() there is.

Comment: @Benji with `var img = $("div:last");` you are targeting the `div`, not the `img` inside it, therefor you are trying to change the `src` of `div`. With `.find('img')` you target the `img` inside of `div`.